Web3Button from Thirdweb-dev/react v4 sdk never loads, when set the active chain to base
i am working on a simple project, im using react v4 sdk , and everithing runds fine, im able to connect the wallet and read data from the users wallet.
but when i set up the web3 button to sing a transaction, basically never loads. it stays rendering.
this is how my thirdweb provider is set up
root.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ThirdwebProvider clientId={_clientId} secretKey={_secreteKey} 
           locale={spanish}
           activeChain={Base}>
             
        <App />
      </ThirdwebProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

this is the component that uses the web3Button
    console.log('approve component');

    const  {contract}  = useContract(tokenAddress);
    const { mutateAsync, isLoading, error } = useContractWrite(
        contract,
        'approve(address spender,uint256 amount)'
    );
    const spender = `${process.env.REACT_APP_MANGO_ROUTER00}`;

    return(
        <Web3Button
            contractAddress={tokenAddress}
            // Calls the "approve" function on erc20 contract
            action={() => mutateAsync({ args: [spender,amount]})}
            className="w-100" 
            style={{
                padding: "1rem",
                fontSize: "1.5rem",
                backgroundColor: "#F26E01", // Mango orange
                borderColor: "#FFA500", // Match the border color
                color: "#FFFFFF", // White text for contrast
            }}
            >Approve</Web3Button>
    );

}
export default ApproveButton;

if a remove the activeChain from the thirdwebprovider wrapper , the buttons loads fine, but can do anything cus is not on the right chain. maybe i need to pass a rpc to the web3 button but not sure


From the attached GitHub repo in the comments, I can see that in your ConnectWalletButton component, where you're rendering the ApproveButton, you need to pass the tokenAddress and amount parameters that it's expecting.
So, in your connectWalletButton.js file, replace this line:
return (<ApproveButton/>);

with:
return (<ApproveButton tokenAddress={addressToken1} amount={amount} />);

Also, in your ThirdwebProvider component wrapper, retain the activeChain field instead of the sdkOptions, like:
<ThirdwebProvider
        clientId={_clientId}
        secretKey={_secreteKey}
        locale={spanish}
        activeChain={Base}
>
  <App />
</ThirdwebProvider>

The Web3Button named as Approve gets loaded and displayed successfully:


thank you i will try this out  happy holidays

it dont work, is weird, becase if i take the activeChain statement from the wrapper, the component loads but is default to main, and it askme to chain to main.
but as soon as the activeChain statement is in place it just loads for ever.
also i tried setting up via defaultOptions like is specified here:  link .

Happy holidays to you too. Can you share your codebase via GitHub repo?

It feels like the issue might be with the component itself. Even after setting the desiredOptions, including a custom RPC and all other configurations, if the activeChain statement is present on the ThirdWebProvider wrapper, it just keeps loading.
If I remove the activeChain, the Web3Button defaults to the Ethereum mainnet. It seems like the Web3Button component isn’t able to communicate properly with the thirwebWrapper provider.

yes this is the github repo link current branch I'm working on is dev-react
also if you want to ask more questions feel free to hit me in X link

I've edited my answer. Please check.
